# Return variable from timerClass

Tags: java, return

So i'm trying to make a speedrun clock and I dont know how to get the variable "i" in `class timerClass extends TimerTask` to return to my main. Any Ideas?

```
class timerClass extends TimerTask {   
    @Override
    public void run() {       
        System.out.println(i++);
    }
    int i = 0; 
}
```

Comment: A class cannot return a value but you can access it using `timerClassInstance.i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class cannot return a value.

You have two options to access `i` from `main()`.

**1-** Use a function to return `i` and call that function from the `main()`.

**2-** Simply access `i` from main by using an object of your `timerClass`.

```
timerClass obj = new timerClass();
System.out.println(obj.i);
```

**Tip**: if `i` us public, you can simply access it by using an object of your class. If `i` is private variable, use a function that returns `i` and call it from `main()` using an object of your class.